# How can i find the Office 365 Release Version Programatically?

Tags: office365, registry, ms-office, versioning

I am looking for a place in the registry or a file contents/property that I can scrape via a script to pull the Windows Release.

For clarification:
I am trying to locate the Release version number of my office 365 installation. I am not asking about the version number of Office, but instead the "Release" (which Microsoft confusingly sometimes calls version number). By "Release" I am talking about the big patch which was previously called a "Service Pack" is distributed roughly twice a year depending on your update channel. So far this has been a 4 digit number, i.e. 2005 for 2020-May. I know I can see the Release number by opening up O365 Word, clicking "Account", and looking in the bottom right under "About Word". Currently for me it shows:

```
Version 2005 (Build 12827.20336 Click-to-Run)
```

In this case 2005 is the Release number. How/where can I pull this information programactically via a script?

Answer (score 0):

The Office extensibility model doesn't provide any property or method for that. You can retrieve the version build numbers (also you may check the file version) and find the corresponding version number according to the information listed on the [Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date) page.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely Microsoft has a hard coded table in every office exe; this sort of a solution is a hack and not what I am looking for. I know that the windows release is stored somewhere.. just don't know where what dll / file / manifest it sits in.